# Preannihilator of the image of an adjoint of a bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $E,F$ be normed spaces and $F\colon E\rightarrow F$ be a linear bounded operator. Denote by $$A'\colon F'\rightarrow E'$$ the adjoint of the operator between the topological duals of the normed spaces. Using Hahn-Banach, one can easily show, that $$closure(image(A))=\{e\in E|\phi(e)=0\ \forall\phi\in kernel(A')\}.$$ Some lecture notes I am using claims, that also the equality
$$closure(image(A'))=\{\phi\in E'|\phi(x)=0\ \forall x\in kernel(A)\}$$ holds. I think that's wrong and one has only the (trivial) inclusion $\subseteq$ of the second equality, but I wasn't able to cook up a counterexample. Does someone know some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use standard notation of annihilator and preannihilator. In fact
$$
\operatorname{Im}(T)\; \text{is closed }\Longleftrightarrow\;\operatorname{Im}(T^*)=(\operatorname{Ker}(T))^\perp
$$
So the desired counterexample among operators with non-closed image. Consider diagonal operator
$$
T:\ell_1\to\ell_1:(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mapsto (\lambda_n x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}
$$
where $\lambda\in c_0$ with non zero entries.

You can check that $\operatorname{Im}(T^*)\subsetneq \ell_\infty$ since $\operatorname{dist}((1,1,\ldots),\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{Im}(T^*)))\geq\frac{1}{2}$, but $\operatorname{Ker}(T)^\perp=\{0\}^\perp=\ell_\infty$

Comment: This works not for all $\lambda$ with nonzero entries, but for example for those, which come arbitrary close to $0$. Thanks, Norbert!

Comment: Tina, thank you for this corretion!